# Swipe all listview/recyclerview to right at once like Snapchat

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, swipe

I want to swipe right all list items inside a listview to reveal some more details about that list item.

Currently with [this](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) library I am able to swipe single items, or multiple items but one after the another. Swiping all at once is necessary.

Snapchat does it already with its messages to reveal message timestamp.

How can this be done?

Comment: can you share video of animation you are talking about?

Comment: @Mani: This: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2r7typ4q8dffpxq/Video%204-4-17%2C%205%2042%2021%20PM.mov?dl=0
For all items in the listview